Error: Cannot find type 'NSURLSessionConfigurationProvider' in ExpoFetchCustomExtension while using in-app purchases in React Native
I am developing a React Native app using Expo and have recently added in-app purchase dependencies. I am encountering the following error messages:
    ❌ (node_modules/expo/ios/Fetch/ExpoFetchCustomExtension.swift:9:75)

7 | public class ExpoFetchCustomExtension: NSObject { 8 | @objc

9 | public static func setCustomURLSessionConfigurationProvider(_ provider: NSURLSessionConfigurationProvider?) { | ^ cannot find type 'NSURLSessionConfigurationProvider' in scope 10 | urlSessionConfigurationProvider = provider 11 | } 12 | }

❌ (node_modules/expo/ios/Fetch/ExpoFetchModule.swift:6:47)

4 | 5 | private let fetchRequestQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "expo.modules.fetch.RequestQueue")

6 | internal var urlSessionConfigurationProvider: NSURLSessionConfigurationProvider? | ^ cannot find type 'NSURLSessionConfigurationProvider' in scope 7 | 8 | public final class ExpoFetchModule: Module { 9 | private lazy var urlSession = createURLSession()

Steps Taken:

Checked the Expo SDK version and ensured compatibility with in-app purchases.
Updated all dependencies using expo install.
Cleaned the build with expo start -c.
Verified that all necessary imports are present in the Swift files.
Reinstalled node modules by deleting node_modules and package-lock.json, then running npm install.
Ensured Xcode is updated to the latest version.
Checked the iOS deployment target in the Podfile.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? What steps can I take to resolve the 'cannot find type' error? Are there any known compatibility issues with the current Expo SDK and in-app purchases?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
